# How to show total item of the listview?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

Please help me. I want to show total items of the list view in the card. Basically, first it will show all 3 category. If you click one of the category it will show all the list of item. So, the problem I want to solve is to show the total of item based on the category.

Coding below i tried using .length and List but it does not show the total of item I register.

```
class CaseListCategory extends StatefulWidget {

  const CaseListCategory ({Key? key}) : super (key : key);

  @override
  _CaseListCategoryState createState() => _CaseListCategoryState();
}

class _CaseListCategoryState extends State<CaseListCategory> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final docCase = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('cases').doc();

    List<CriticalCaseList> cases = [];
    
    return Scaffold(
     
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => CriticalCaseList(),
                ),
              );
            },
            child: Card(
              elevation: 10,
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30, horizontal: 10),
                child: Container(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'CRITICAL',
                        style: TextStyle(letterSpacing: 1.0,fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      Text(         
                        "${cases.length}",
                        style: TextStyle(letterSpacing: 1.0,fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ), 
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => ModerateCaseList(),
              ),
            );
          },
          child: Card(
            elevation: 10,
            color: Colors.orange,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30, horizontal: 10),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "MODERATE",
                    style: TextStyle(letterSpacing: 1.0,fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  Text(         
                    "${cases.length}",
                    style: TextStyle(letterSpacing: 1.0,fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => LowCaseList(),
              ),
            );
          },
          child: Card(
            elevation: 10,
            color: Colors.yellow,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30, horizontal: 10),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'LOW',
                    style: TextStyle(letterSpacing: 1.0,fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  Text(         
                    "${cases.length}",
                    style: TextStyle(letterSpacing: 1.0,fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        ],), 
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Here are the coding of page after i click the card. it show all of item

[Category page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBJDg.png)
[List of item page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giACu.png)

```
class CriticalCaseList extends StatefulWidget {
  const CriticalCaseList ({Key? key}) : super (key : key);

  @override
  
  _CriticalCaseListState createState() => _CriticalCaseListState();
}

class _CriticalCaseListState extends State<CriticalCaseList> {
  User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

  final CollectionReference _cases = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('cases');

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      
    return Scaffold(

      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Critical Case"),
        backgroundColor: Colors. redAccent,
        centerTitle: true,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          color: Colors.white,
          iconSize: 30,
          onPressed: () =>  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const VolunteerPage())),
        ),
      ),

      // Using StreamBuilder to display all products from Firestore in real-time
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: _cases.snapshots(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> streamSnapshot) {
          if (streamSnapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: streamSnapshot.data!.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {

                final DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = streamSnapshot.data!.docs[index];
                  if(documentSnapshot['priority'] == "Critical" && documentSnapshot['status'] == "Waiting for rescue"){
                  return Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(documentSnapshot['name']),
                      subtitle: Text(documentSnapshot['priority'].toString()),
                      trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(context, 
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CaseListView(cid: documentSnapshot['cid']))
                        );
                      },
                    )
                  );
                  
                }
                return Card();
                },
              );
            }
            return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce your code, please provide the full codes and their files. I can't tell which snippet is CaseListView or CriticalCaseList or _cases

Comment: i have update the coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Problems

There are two problems with the code.

1. In `CriticalCaseList`, documentSnapshot is a snapshot and not the document data itself, so you need to access data from it after calling `.data()` on the documentSnapshot.
2. In `CaseListCategory`, `cases.length` is not working because there is no part of the code that is filling up `cases` from Firestore.
3. It will be improper to use `cases.length` because `cases` will contain the total of all the cases (irrespective of their categories). But you want the individual totals of critical, moderate, or low categories.

##### Solution

So in `CriticalCaseList`, change the following line

```dart
final DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = streamSnapshot.data!.docs[index];
```

to

```dart
final DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = streamSnapshot.data!.docs[index].data();
```

(notice .data() appended at the end)

Given that you want to display the total number of cases in each category, what you can do is keep track of each categories total.

So you can have variables for each of them. Then initialize their values in `initState`. And still in `initState`, you can use `.snapshots().listen()` on the collection reference of cases. This way, every time cases are added or removed, The `CaseListCategory` widget will update the total of each case and display the current total. Also, remember to cancel the StreamSubscription in `dispose()`.

Finally, in the parts of the code where you display the totals, instead of using `cases.length`, you use the total of the given category. The following should work:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'critical_case_list.dart';
import 'moderate_case_list.dart';
import 'low_case_list.dart';

class CaseListCategory extends StatefulWidget {
  const CaseListCategory({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CaseListCategoryState createState() => _CaseListCategoryState();
}

class _CaseListCategoryState extends State<CaseListCategory> {
  double _criticalCases = 0, _moderateCases = 0, _lowCases = 0;
  late StreamSubscription _listener;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _listener = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('cases')
        .snapshots()
        .listen((snap) {
      final cases = snap.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
      _criticalCases = 0;
      _moderateCases = 0;
      _lowCases = 0;
      for (var caseData in cases) {
        if (caseData['priority'] == 'Critical') _criticalCases++;
        if (caseData['moderate'] == 'Moderate') _moderateCases++;
        if (caseData['low'] == 'Low') _lowCases++;
      }
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _listener.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => CriticalCaseList(),
                ),
              );
            },
            child: Card(
              elevation: 10,
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30, horizontal: 10),
                child: Container(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'CRITICAL',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            letterSpacing: 1.0,
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        '$_criticalCases',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            letterSpacing: 1.0,
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => ModerateCaseList(),
                ),
              );
            },
            child: Card(
              elevation: 10,
              color: Colors.orange,
              child: Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30, horizontal: 10),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "MODERATE",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          letterSpacing: 1.0,
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      '$_moderateCases',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          letterSpacing: 1.0,
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => LowCaseList(),
                ),
              );
            },
            child: Card(
              elevation: 10,
              color: Colors.yellow,
              child: Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30, horizontal: 10),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'LOW',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          letterSpacing: 1.0,
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      '$_lowCases',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          letterSpacing: 1.0,
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

##### Better solution

Your current setup is expensive. Or rather, it will be costly as your app grows or scales. Firebase charges you for every document read. That said, every time `CaseListCategory` is loaded, Firestore will read **all the documents** in the *cases* collection. And every time any document in that collection is created, updated, or deleted, Firestore will fetch all of them again (to update the totals).

A common pattern to reduce such cost is to have a *counters* collection. Inside it, you will have documents for each category that will maybe have a *total* property, holding the current total of a given category.

Then you increment or decrement the current count of a given category when a case is created or deleted. A better place to run this logic is in Cloud Functions, where you are sure that the code would run. Updating the counts in clients is not recommended because the client's network might fail or also for security reasons.

So you could have the following code in cloud functions in `index.js` file.

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.incrementCaseCount = functions.firestore
  .document('/cases/{caseId}')
  .onCreate(async (snap, _) => {
    const category = snap.data()['priority'].toLowerCase();
    await db
      .doc(`/counters/${category}Cases`)
      .set({ total: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1) }, { merge: true })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  });

exports.decrementCaseCount = functions.firestore
  .document('/cases/{caseId}')
  .onDelete(async (snap, _) => {
    const category = snap.data()['priority'].toLowerCase();
    await db
      .doc(`/counters/${category}Cases`)
      .set({ total: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1) }, { merge: true })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  });
```

And then in flutter, in the `initState` of `CaseListCategory`, instead of listening to snapshots of the entire *cases* collection, you can listen to snapshots of only the *counters* collection. *counters* collection would have a small number of documents, so it is cheaper to read from them than to read all the documents in the *cases* collection.

So you can have the following in `initState`.

```dart
    _listener = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('counters')
        .snapshots()
        .listen((snap) {
      for (var doc in snap.docs) {
        if (doc.id == 'criticalCases') _criticalCases = doc.data()['total'];
        if (doc.id == 'moderateCases') _moderateCases = doc.data()['total'];
        if (doc.id == 'lowCases') _lowCases = doc.data()['total'];
      }
      setState(() {});
    });
```

Comment: And @mihab, if you are interested in following up with cloud functions and if the priority of the cases can change, then be aware that there is also `functions.firestore.document().onUpdate()`, that a function with take a change parameter. Change contains before and after of the document state. So from there you can detect which categories to update if the priority changed.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I have tried your suggestion but the counter still not going up after i create new cases

Comment: Oh, I think I have noticed why, let me update the answer

Comment: I've made the update, append .data() to documentSnapshot, and you might have to stop your app and start back flutter run to see the change because we have changed initState

Comment: I don't know why but still nothing changed. Appreciate your help

Comment: will you mind sharing your screen on a Google Meet call ? if you can send a link and I join

Comment: https://meet.google.com/xbx-avoq-yci